# How can I add Disqus commenting to my Gollum wiki?

Tags: disqus, gollum-wiki

I would like to use my Gollum Wiki (using aws & github) for a book project. I want to give each chapter its own page and let a circle of friends (and anyone) leave comments. I was expecting there to be a dozen how to pages for this already out there. But I can't find anything. I realize this usually means what I'm trying to do is a bad idea or can more easily be accomplished some other way.

Answer (score 1):

The way I added Disqus comments was to simply add a mustache partial template (`{{>comments}}`)  that contains the Disqus embed code, and then modified the stock `page.template` to reference it.

Finally, I copied all stock templates plus the new `comments.mustache` and modified `page.mustache` ones to a location of my choice and pointed Gollum to it via the `template-dir` option.

See also [Gollum's issue #1222](https://github.com/gollum/gollum/issues/1222) and the [Gollum installation guide](https://wiki.davidplanella.org/open-source/gollum-wiki-installation) I wrote for more details.