# add disqus commenting to gollum

Tags: localhost, disqus, gollum-wiki, universal-code

I am a n00b so please bear with my stupidity here.

What I am trying to do is add `disqus commenting` to `gollumwiki`.

First of all, is it alright to give `localhost` as my website URL on the disqus website where I am registering the website? I hope not. If not, should I get a publicly accessible domain for that?

Secondly, where should I add the universal code to embed disqus on my website? 
I tried adding to the .mustache template file but it doesn't work. I also tried adding to index.html in one of the folders, but the website is obviously generating from the template.

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739913/how-can-i-add-disqus-commenting-to-my-gollum-wiki) link here but no answers.

I looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475821/disqus-comments-fails-to-load-on-localhost) too. But I need to clarify my doubts before I go ahead.

I would like to add that the .mustache files have not been changing (adding the disqus tag) on inspection. If that's the case how do I make sure they change? I tried deleting caches from browser. Doesn't work.

Comment: Please see the answer to this same question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/21739913/1049318